# What does the IE "Display intranet sites in compatibility mode" option do? Why is it a default in IE?

Tags: windows-8, display-settings, slideshow, internet-explorer-11

What does the "Display intranet sites in compatibility mode" option in IE mean exactly?  Why would it be the default?

I design and develop with Mac vs PC so I am not particularly savvy when it comes to Windows/IE problems at all.

Client is hosting a Wordpress site I developed and it runs on a Ubuntu server they installed in-house.  Their previous website was hosted on their Windows server which they run everything else on.
Here is one of the portfolio pages: http://grlarchitects.com/liberty-mutual-insurance-group/

2 months after we launch the site they say the format of their website portfolio pages when viewed through Windows 8.1 and IE 11 are showing thumbnails stacking rather inline.  When they disable this compatibility mode, the format is fine.

My question is why would they need their workstations to display intranet sites in compatibility mode?  Their previous website was hosted on the Windows server.

They have always run in compatibly mode, its the default on all their workstations.  What has changed is they upgraded to IE 11/Win 8.1 in December.  Is it reasonable to tell them to disable compatibility mode on all their workstations?  Are there other reasons they need to run in compatibility mode?

Although they are saying this just happened - I am not sure the site was ever tested in IE in-house - my browser tests all worked with Browserstack with IE and still do with that configuration.
And I don't know if that many people even use IE in their office.

Also - when I recreate these portfolio pages in my test site which is hosted through HostGator they don't see the problem at all when viewing in compatibility mode on IE.

I should also say that I have ruled out Wordpress theme and plugin conflicts.  And I can recreate the problem through Firebug/FF on my Mac when I comment out a display:inline-block in the css:

```
.mg-image-showcase .mg-thumbs ul li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
 }
```

If I use a float:left instead and add list-style:none; I can get it align properly.

```
.mg-image-showcase .mg-thumbs ul li {
  /*display: inline-block !important;*/
    position: relative !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
    float:left;
    list-style: none;
 }
```

I have not yet tested this with the client.

I would love to hear any thoughts on this, it would be so appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I got the answer through another post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269781/why-compatibility-mode-for-intranet-sites